# "error.ReactorNotRestartable() twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable"- Binance websocket api

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, twisted, binance

I am getting an issue with websocket. Any example I run from https://github.com/Binance-docs/binance-futures-connector-python/tree/main/examples/websocket/futures gives me the following error - "WARNING:root:WebSocket connection closed: connection was closed uncleanly (peer dropped the TCP connection without previous WebSocket closing handshake), code: 1006, clean: False, reason: connection was closed uncleanly (peer dropped the TCP connection without previous WebSocket closing handshake)".

Whenever I try to rerun the examples I get the error "error.ReactorNotRestartable()
twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable".

I have found out that I can escape this error by uninstalling and then reinstalling the twisted library. But then I have to repeat the reinstallment every time I want to start the websocket. Since this isn't a feasible solution. Can someone here help me with how to resolve this issue? What would be the most appropriate way to close the websocket connection since
`ws_client = FuturesWebsocketClient(), ws_client.stop()` 
is causing this issue.

Comment: is there a particular `file` from that link that you are trying to run ?  And also, have you tried the quick start guide here:  https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: any file I run from the link gives me the same error. With regards to the official documentation, it deals with Binance spot and not Binance futures.

Comment: How are you running the examples?

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone I am running it on a Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Twisted's reactors are presently not restartable.  You can install at most one per process and you can run it at most once.

Your Jupyer notebook is running in a single long-lived Python process so you are limited to a single of whatever run-the-reactor interaction you are attempting.

I don't know what you mean by "uninstalling and reinstalling Twisted" but the general solution is to arrange your code so that you only need to run a Twisted reactor once (ie, don't stop it before you're done with everything you want to do) or contribute restartable reactors to Twisted.

Or, perhaps, stop running your code in a Jupyter Notebook and run it in something with a different process lifetime instead.

Comment: thanks a lot, working well with .py files, problem only when running on .ipynb file

Answer (score 0):

Please have a try with the latest version, the Websocket part has been redesigned.